# Where to validate uniqueness of field in Spring/Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation

I am building a REST API using spring and hibernate. I have come across the issue where I want to create a user and want to know the best practice on how to validate that the user can be created.

My controller has the @Valid annotation on the User object that gets passed into the method, and this checks for valid structure, however there is no @Unique property that gets picked up by @Valid.

I am using the @Column(unique = true) but this throws an error at the persistence level and I feel like that is quite low level and makes it difficult to throw a custom UsernameAlreadyExistsException().

My question here is what is the best practice in terms of preforming this type of validation. I thought about creating a custom annotation but it seems quite messy especially because as the project grows I would need multiple validators for different fields and it also seems to be closley related to tying the service layer to the annotation which seems messy

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, using custom annotation is the best approach to do stuff like this, you can inject some bean in ConstraintValidator and perform validation. However you can try one of the below unusual approaches, maybe it will fit your requirements.

- [Spring AOP](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop)
- [Spring Handler Interceptor](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor)
- [JPA Event Listeners](https://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa)

It's just my opinion about this, in most cases I think I will create custom annotations to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

A good practice would be to put validation both on the database (which we know nothing about, but it is not complicated really) and on the Spring's side.

As @kamil-w already said, a good is to write custom constraint validator, see [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator) for an example.

Keep in mind that you can always pass parameters like to constraint annotation, and then access them in your ConstraintValidator, for example.:

```
@Entity
public class Member {
  // ...
 @UniqueField(fieldName = "login", context = Member.class)
 private String login;
}



@Component
public class UniqueFieldValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueField, Object> {
 @PersistenceUnit
 private EntityManagerFactory emf;
 private Class validationContext;
 private String fieldName;

  @Override
  public void initialize(UniqueField uniqueField) {
    this.validationContext = uniqueField.validationContext();
    this.fieldName = uniqueField.fieldName();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {
    // use value, this.validationContext, this.fieldName and entity manager to check uniqueness
  }

}
```